# Ubuntu Server - Apache2 - Files show as raw data

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, apache2, display

Ubuntu server running Apache2 and then I try to display a PDF or PNG file it shows the raw file, not the graphical view. Using different browsers do not open the file in normal viewing mode, but shows the raw data.

Example: https://docs/mydoc.pdf
Result: %PDF-1.7 %���� 1 0 obj <> endobj 2 0 obj <> endobj 3 0 obj <> endobj 4 0 obj <> strea

Same file on another server opens as you'd expect.

Different browsers same results. Checked mime.types for pdf entry.